# Issues On JSON File

Tags: javascript

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {
    let Com_Title = req.query.ComTitle;
    let Com_Text = req.query.ComText;
    let data = {
        Title: Com_Title,
        Text: Com_Text,
    }
    console.log(data);
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    // fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', dataJSON)
    // let MyData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    fs.appendFileSync('ComplaintFile.json', jsonData, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(404).end();
        }
        console.log('Data Added');
        res.send('Added');
    })
});

let port = 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening to 8080");
})
```

```
{
    "Title": "Canteen Issues",
    "Text": "A paragraph"
}{
    "Title": "Canteen ",
    "Text": "Topic sentences are similar "
}
```

I have issues on saving data in JSON. Actually is saving the data on JSON file but it have comma issues like if I add one or more data that next data storing without the comma.

Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: You need to open the file, parse the contents of the file as JSON then append the new data to that then save it.

Comment: You code does not show/explain how you end up with the data example that you show. It would be interesting to see how the array of the two objects is made.

Comment: Can You Give a Example of it

Answer (score 2):

Using [appendfilesync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) is not appropriate for storing JSON data like that because JSON is structured data and appendfilesync will just add data to the end of the file. You need to:

1. Read the data that is already in the file.
2. Parse the data as JSON.
3. Add the new data to the JSON object/array.
4. Stringify the JSON data.
5. Save the data to the file.

In this example the initial file would look like this:

```
[{"Title":"Title","Text":"Content"}]
```

So, it is an array. And you can then add objects to that array.

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("data.json", function(err, buf) {
  let dataStr = buf.toString();
  let dataObj = JSON.parse(dataStr);
  let newData = {Title: "Title", Text: "Content"};
  dataObj.push(newData); // assuming that this is an array

  let newDataStr = JSON.stringify(dataObj);

  fs.writeFile("data.json", newDataStr, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
  });
});
```

Comment: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object

Comment: @RakulAgn I added example code. I hope it helps with that error.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data correctly, you just **need to get data** from file if exist then append new data with previous data.

Comment: Actual think is I need to add one or more Data but if I use WriteFilesync The new Data is Overwriting on pervious One Thats Why i Used Append Option But I got issues on that to its adding all data but without the comma which means its not like next data right ?

Comment: You can use **appendFile** function, Always append , with each write except first write on file.